# Poll Angular Observable<number> at set intervals

Tags: angular, pipe, observable

I have an observable that I know has an update rate of about 100 values per second. What I want is to just poll its current value at a fraction of that update rate, say 5 times per second, so that I can display it.

```
highFrequencyData$: Observable<number> = this.myHighFrequencyDataService.highFrequencyData$;

// This update rate is way too high and not what I want:
highFrequencyData$.subscribe( (value: number) => this.displayValue(value) );
```

I'm relatively new to Angular and I feel there is an elegant way to do the following using pipes and timers and what not, but I can't figure out the correct syntax for it. My goal is to transform this into a low-frequency Observable that I can use further on, like:

```
lowFrequencyData$ : Observable<number>  = highFrequencyData$.pipe( /* Magic happens to pick value at frequency of 5Hz */);
```

What is the correct way to formulate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is simple, just learn RxJS to use it easy in future... :

```
const refreshRate = 200; // refresh rate in ms

lowFrequencyData$: Observable<number> = highFrequencyData$.pipe(debounceTime(refreshRate));
```